# System V IPC & new

Tags: c++, linux, new-operator

I'm new in Linux C and C++ programming. I'm trying to create a C++ class for system v ipc message queue and I have 1 problem.
I wrote class for message like this:

```
class message
{
    friend class queue;
private:
    typedef struct
    {
        long mtype;
    char mdata[maxmsg_buf];
    }msgbuf_t, *msgbuf_ptr_t;

    msgbuf_ptr_t msgbuf_ptr;
public:
    message(void):msgbuf_ptr(NULL)
    {
        msgbuf_ptr = new msgbuf_t;
    }
    ipc::message::message(const long& type, const std::string& data):msgbuf_ptr(NULL)
    {
    msgbuf_ptr = new msgbuf_t;

    msgbuf_ptr->mtype = type;
    if(data.length() <= maxmsg_buf)
    {
    strncpy(msgbuf_ptr->mdata, data.c_str(), data.length());
    }
    }
};

class queue
{
private:
    mutable qid_t qid;
public:
    queue(const key_t& qkey = unique, const perm_t& qperm = usr_rw, const flag_t& qflag = none)
    {
         qid = msgget(qkey, qperm | qflag);
    if(qid == -1)
    {
    throw errno;                //specify exception for queue  
    }
    }
    void send(const ipc::message& msg, const int& sflag) const
    {
    if((msgsnd(qid, &msg.msgbuf_ptr, sizeof(msg.msgbuf_ptr->mdata), sflag)) == -1)
    {
    throw errno;                //specify exception for queue 
    }
    }
};


//Usage:
ipc::queue q(0x0000FFFF, ipc::usr_rw, ipc::create);
ipc::message msg(10L, "First test message for sysVipc queue");

q.send(msg);   //throws EFAULT from here
```

When I send msgbuf_ptr  to msgsnd syscall, it returns EFAULT(Bad address) error. So my question is: may I allocate msgbuf using operator new?
P.S. Sorry, if my english is not well.

Comment: Show us the call of msgsnd in your code.

Comment: More code is needed. Please post the place where you actually send the message and initialize pointer.

Comment: On a side-note: You are programming in C++ and there the syntax of struct declaration is the same as for class declaration, so *don't use the typedef*. And don't typedef pointers. Unless they are opaque handles it's only confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your queue::send method.
`&msg.msgbuf_ptr` is a pointer to a pointer. Omit the address operator `&` and you should be fine.

EDIT: no wait
`msg.msgbuf_ptr->mdata` is your message.
So, you should call it this way:
`msgsnd(qid, &msg.msgbuf_ptr + sizeof(msg.msgbuf.mtype), sizeof(msg.msgbuf_ptr->mdata), sflag)`